# WebView + Blob URL + Download Image

Tags: android, image, webview, download, bloburls

After a Long Time, I was Used WebView. so let me ask what I have a phase issue.

-I had Google for `Blob URL` but I hvnt find a solution OR Any hint so I have to post Question HERE.

-I have `WebView` at the android side to Load A website.  At their On Button to `"SAVE-AS" to download an image`.

-Now when I trying it on  `Google Chrome app` yeah its `working` `fine` and download properly.

-Now the same  scenario with `webview` at my app at `DownloadListener` 
I got Blob URL something like

> blob:http://-----cantshare-----.com/7e7452c8-62ca-4231-8640-0e9de715e073

So downloadmanger `download nothing`

**Check my code**

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

final ProgressDialog progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(this, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
        if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);

    }
});

webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

        Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);

        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            webpage = Uri.parse("http://" + url);
        }

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                webpage);


        request.setMimeType(mimetype);


        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);


        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);


        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);


        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");


        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                mimetype));


        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();


        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Main2Activity.this,
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,".pdf");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

**Q1** -Can Anyone give suggestion How to download File From Blob URL ?
**Q2** - Have to change At Server side ?
**Q3** - any other ways instead of Downloadermanager?

### Edit

I tried  `.pdf /.png/.jpeg` but `no luck`  ;(

```
setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Main2Activity.this,
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,".pdf");
```

Comment: have you download file or not ?

Comment: Any luck with reading blob?

Answer (score 5):

I was in the same nightmare. What I did is convert the Blob URL data in Base64 String and with this string I created a ".pdf" file. Take a look of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954970).

Comment: Hi Kevin... please update your answer at snippet *..look of my answer..* to match *...look of my SO answer..* in order to avoid people asking you to post code.. And add a dot at the end ;p